# Как искать в БД mysql умный поиск

Tags: php, mysql

Задача в том что есть магазин, там товары (>50к)
у товара есть поля название, краткое_описание, полное, характеристики.

нужно если мы ищем например "жесткий диск" он сначала смотрел 
название, выводил их первыми там где полное совпадение, 
потом тех, где частичное совпадение, 
потом тех, у которых совпадения в кратком, 
потом в полном....

есть ли какой то мега запрос **mysql**, который отранжирует записи так? или надо применять

**union select + like**

мне говорят мол **лайк** ваще не используй, он очень грузит сервер, особенно если дохрена товаров...

Comment: [Полнотекстовый поиск в MySQL][1] [1]:http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Fulltext_Search.html

Comment: А как сделать чтобы он реагировал на короткие слова 3 буквы хоть на - 
а то если указать "наушники" ищет а "наушники 869" показывает тот же результат...

Comment: Попробуй sphinx (http://sphinxsearch.com/) прикрутить.

Comment: Проблема 3-ех буков решается правкой конфигов

Comment: @armenka, на три буквы лучше не надо :) правда - слишком много всего найдет, пользы никакой. про релевантность читайте в статье. фильтруйте результаты, отрезая "плохие" записи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно настроить в my.ini (файл конфигурации MySQL)

```
[mysqld]
```

добавить
`ft_min_word_len = 3`(чтобы можно было искать слова из трех букв, например PHP)
`ft_stopword_file` (txt файл указываем - список стоп слов для поиска)
Вот и всё!

Comment: ммм а если сервер то не мой, а хостера, врядли он будет что то настраивать
и еще чето у меня с JOIN запросом жутко тормозит MATCH с чем это связано?

Comment: Попробуй переписать запрос так, чтобы не использовать JOIN!